# MDCBottomSheet in swift

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, bottom-sheet

[This is how I want to show the bottomsheet above navigation bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Qua.png)I want to build MDCBottomSheet in IOS swift but want to be presented above the bottom navigation bar.

```
    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item.tag == 4{
        let vc = tempVC()
        let bottomSheet: MDCBottomSheetController = MDCBottomSheetController(contentViewController: vc)
        present(bottomSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }}
```

in tempVC() there is only one line view. background = .yellow

but by doing this bottomsheet is coming from bottom not above the navigation bar.[This is how my code is working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0L1Q.png)
please help me to show this bottomsheet above Tabbarvc()

Comment: Bottomsheet never touches NavighationBar Thas why its not touching that. For that you should try model presentation with .overfullscreen style.

Comment: but now there is an error -----.application tried to present modally a view controller <MDCBottomSheetController: 0x7ff93353a6e0> that has a parent view controller

Comment: @Kudos still coming over the navigation bar. I want above the navigation bar.

Comment: @SahilParashar did you find any solution for this issue ?

Comment: @AakashGupta Yes i did customization.

Comment: @SahilParashar great, can you please share the customization changes you did for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Present method cannot achieve your effect, you need to customize the view, add it to the current view, and then add animation effects to achieve